# How to find links containing a specific word in case insensitive manner in selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to be able to find links containing: hello, Hello, hEllo, heLlo, etc. So far I'm using `find_elements_by_partial_link_text` which is casse sensitive:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('hello')
```

Answer (score 8):

`find_elements_by_partial_link_text()` as well as `find_elements_by_link_text()` are both *case sensitive* and the behavior cannot be easily changed.

Instead, find links [by xpath](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath) and apply [`lower-case()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893551/case-insensitive-matching-in-xpath):

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(lower-case(.), "hello")]')
```

Also see:

- [Is there a way to ignore upper case when trying to find a link by linkText with Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385459/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-upper-case-when-trying-to-find-a-link-by-linktext-with)

Comment: I assume the `matches()` cannot be used because of the limitation of xpath 1.0?