# Match Case and Exact Match in XML Document with XPath

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, xpath

How to **match the case in xml node data**. I need to search the xml node data and match the given string with xml node data.
**Matching is required on:**

- Match Case
- Exact Match

Any help in this regard is warmly welcom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `lower-case()` and `upper-case()` are only available in XPath 2.0 and upper versions.

**In XPath 1.0 for case-insensitive string comparison use**:

```
translate($string1, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
=
 translate($string2, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

where `$string1` and `$string2` are expressions specifying the strings to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at section 7.6.2 of the XPath spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches

With the `fn:matches`function you write a regular expression to match your desired target string.

Cheers,

Comment: I'm not supposed to match xml node data with some pattern here. But, node element data with user input value. I've a sub-child of book node. `<book> <title>ASP.NET</title> </book>` and user input a value in text box *asp.net*. Here, I need to match the case. My xpath expression which returs the title of book is: `"book[title='"+txtBookTitle.text+"']"` Can you shed some light how to achieve this ?

Comment: The function fn:matches works on element data, so I would expect that something like `/book[fn:matches( title , '.*asp.net.*' )]` works for you (the `asp.net` is of course your query string). Come to think of it, `fn:contains` may also work, although I'm unsure of the case-sensitivity...

Answer (score 0):

Try [`lower-case` or `upper-case`](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string) String functions. That's not quite the same as *case-insensitive*, but hopefully it will be close enough:

```
//YourNode[lower-case(@title)='anders rostgaard bystru']
```

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625446/problem-with-upper-case-and-lower-case-xpath-functions-in-selenium-ide/1625859#1625859) for other solutions.