# "Code reuse" in an XPath expression

Tags: .net, xpath

Background: I am using HtmlAgilityPack (.Net), so I'm forced to use XPath 1.0, [which doesn't have a lower-case implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1625859/687857).

I am trying to find all the nodes that have an attribute which contains `foo` as a whole word.
Examples:

- "foo" *match*
- "my foo" *match*
- "foo bar" *match*
- "Foo" *match*
- "ifoo" *no match*
- "food" *no match*

This is what I have (there is also no `ends-with` in XPath 1.0...):

```
//*[@*[starts-with(.,'foo ') or contains(.,' foo ') or .='foo' or substring(.,string-length(.) - 3)=' foo']]
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1625859/687857), I can use this horrific method to lower-case the search criteria:

```
translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Finally, my question: **How do I use the `translate` function, while keeping the expression as short and as readable as possible?**

(Bonus: How do I share this between different expressions?)

Comment: What do you mean by "How do I share this between different expressions"? The rest is answered very well by Tomalak -- using a sentinel approach is a well-known technique in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just use** (summarized version of Tomalak's answer):

```
//@*[contains(concat(' ', 
                     translate(normalize-space(), 'FOO', 'foo'), 
                     ' '), 
              ' foo '
              )
    ]
```

**Warning**:

Never insert into an XPath expression placeholder a string received by an unknown agent (end-user). This opens a gaping hole for **[XPath Injection attack](http://www.soapui.org/Security/xpath-injection.html)**.

The recomended practice is to have a *compiled XPath expression* and to pass the user-supplied string as parameter (or **[get them via a variable or function reference](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000385.html)** in the XPath expression)  when the evaluation is done.

Comment: Thanks - much better now... And i'm using a constant, so I have no fear of injections (not 'foo' though).

Comment: @seldary: You are welcome. I'd really recommend using a compiled XPath expression + functions/variables in the context.

Answer (score 1):

How about [adding custom functions to XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950806.aspx)?