# Python: Selenium xpath to find element with case insensitive characters?

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

I am able to do this

```
search = "View List"
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*/text()[normalize-space(.)='%s']/parent::*" % search)
```

but I need it to ignore and match all elements with text like: "VieW LiSt" or "view LIST"

```
search = "View List"
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*/lower-case(text())[normalize-space(.)='%s']/parent::*" % search.lower())
```

The above doesn't seem to work. `lower-case()` is in XPATH 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lower-case()` function is only supported from XPath 2.0. For XPath 1.0 you will have to use `translate()`.

Example code is given in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625446/problem-with-upper-case-and-lower-case-xpath-functions-in-selenium-ide/1625859#1625859).

Edit:
The selenium python bindings site has a FAQ - [Does Selenium 2 supports XPath 2.0 ?](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-selenium-2-supports-xpath-2-0):

> Ref:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#how-xpath-works-in-webdriver
>
> Selenium delegate XPath queries down to the browser’s own XPath
>   engine, so Selenium support XPath supports whatever the browser
>   supports. In browsers which don’t have native XPath engines (IE
>   6,7,8), Selenium support XPath 1.0 only.

Comment: anyway toget xpath 2.0 working in selenium python? that solution is really not optimal

Comment: Unfortunately no. xpath 2.0 needs to be supported by the browser, it is not a selenium/python limitation.

Comment: this is what I'm thinking, use a javascript library that supports xpath 2.0 and inject it in python

Comment: Let us know how you go with that, I would be interested if that works.

Comment: once I figure out how to inject jquery files into selenium python phantomjs

Answer (score 0):

Since `lower-case()` is only supported in 2.0 I came up with this solution using `translate()` so I don't need to type the whole function manually everytime

```py
translate = "translate({value},'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"

driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f"//*/{translate.format(value='text()')}[normalize-space(.)='{search.lower()}']/parent::*")
```

Which computes to:

```py
>>> print(f"//*/{translate.format(value='text()')}[normalize-space(.)='{search.lower()}']/parent::*")
"//*/translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')[normalize-space(.)='view list']/parent::*"
```