# Python selenium presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ) need case insensitive

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, case-sensitive

I stumbled upon fact then `xref` maybe in upper case or lower case (even partly) on searched page. How to ensure script finds xref if xref is present on page regardless of case?

Post [Python: Selenium xpath to find element with case insensitive characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228962/python-selenium-xpath-to-find-element-with-case-insensitive-characters) talks it's not working, but it was 2013. Hope it's changed. How to write proper expression? My current code is:

```
myLink = WebDriverWait(myDriver, 
10).until(ExConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
'//a[starts-with(@href,"https://www.test.org/portal/")]')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `lower-case(@href)` is not working (at least for my Firefox on Windows 7), also not `fn:lower-case(@href)`.

I resort to `translate` which I've found in posts:

```
'//a[contains(translate(@href, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"),
"www.test.org/portal")]'
```

Comment: If you answered your own question, please mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this function.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

def If_element_is_here_do_click(xpath_arg):
        executed = 0
        while (executed == 0):
            try:
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_arg).click()
                executed = 1
                print("Clicked")
            except:
                print("No")
                time.sleep(0.5)
```

And call like this :

```
If_element_is_here_do_click("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button")
```