# Finding the below xpath regardless of the value being lowercase or uppercase

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have the following HTML, where I am trying to match the XPath with the input type = checkbox.

[image]

Here is my xpath below, it seems to work fine when I change the type in the xpath to CheckBox. Is there a way to write a xpath where it ignores lower case and upper case

//tr/th//*[text()="Primary Contact"]./..//..//input[@type="checkbox"]

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/20229258/6626530

Comment: The easiest way is `//input[contains(@type, "heckbox")] ` :)

Comment: @shijo, the answer seems little outdated? Can i use lower or i have to use the translate? It makes the process little complicated.

Comment: Check you xpath version and use the mentioned functionality accordingly