# xpath - upper case and lower case button text

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have multiple ok buttons in my application in the combinations: OK, ok, oK and Ok. How can i write a single @findby expression to identify all of them with the one webelement.
Code example

```
<button type="button">OK</button>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [case-insensitive matching in xpath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893551/case-insensitive-matching-in-xpath)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the other solution in pure xpath 1.0 using xpath functions.

```
 //button[contains('OK,ok,Ok,oK',text())][string-length('OK')=2]
```

or

```
//button[contains('OK,ok,Ok,oK',text())][string-length(text())=string-length('OK')]
```

[image]

**Edit: Simple approach using `translate`**

```
//button[translate(text(),'ok','OK')='OK']
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can specify matching text with xpath:

```
//button[text()='OK']
```

In your case, to match them all:

```
//button[text()='OK' or text()='oK' or text()='ok' or text()='Ok']
```

Comment: or `//button[lower-case(text())=='ok']`

Comment: Except that no major browser appears to support XPath 2.0, which means the `lower-case()` will not be recognized.

Comment: There is a really hacky work around here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625446/problem-with-upper-case-and-lower-case-xpath-functions-in-selenium-ide/1625859#1625859