# Insensitive match of attribute in XPath 1.0?

Tags: html, xpath, match, case

Is there a way to match an attribute in case-insensitive fashion in XPath 1.0?

For example if I have this

```
<input type="submit"></input>
<input type="Submit"></input>
<input type="SUBMIT"></input>
```

I can use `//input[@type='submit']` but it will match only the first element.

Is there a way to match all of the elements regardless case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [case-insensitive matching in xpath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893551/case-insensitive-matching-in-xpath)

Comment: @alecxe no. All solutions in the link is for XPath 2.

Comment: Hm, arguable. In the best-scored answer there is a link to the [`translate()` based hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625446/problem-with-upper-case-and-lower-case-xpath-functions-in-selenium-ide/1625859#1625859) there.

Comment: @alecxe that solution doesn't work for me. If I use `translate()` it will match either the first or last element, not all.

Comment: Then you are not doing it right...

Comment: @BeniBela thanks for the help. Very constructive feedback.

Comment: @Pithikos :) Though, as you see, the thread is very close to be duplicate. And thanks for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out actually. It seems that `@attribute` can be used in place of strings. In that case

```
//input[translate(@type, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')=translate('submit', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')]
```

Will give back all `input` elements where the value to `type` matches "submit", in case-insensitive fashion.