# Filter XMLNodeList using xPath & Wildcard characters

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

I have "XML" as below:

```
<ParentNode>
    <ChildNode id="1" Display_Name="ABC"/>
    <ChildNode id="2" Display_Name="DEF"/>
    <ChildNode id="3" Display_Name="DAX"/>
    <ChildNode id="4" Display_Name="LAM"/>
    <ChildNode id="5" Display_Name="PKR"/>
    <ChildNode id="6" Display_Name="UYA"/>
</ParentNode>
```

I want to get list of all the Nodes in **XMLNodeList** in **C#** using xPath having "A" [regardless of capitals or small] in **Display_Name** attribute.

What I've tried is:

```
root.SelectNodes("descendant-or-self::*[contains(@DISPLAY_NAME,'end')]")
```

Here, root is containing my XML and it is an object of **XMLDocument**.

Also, how can I make this filter by ignoring either **Display_Name** is in *small letters* or *capital letters*.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I want to get list of all the Nodes in `XMLNodeList` in C# using xPath having `"A"` [regardless of capitals or small] in `Display_Name` attribute. "*

Nature of XML and XPath is case-sensitive. There is no pretty way to do case-insensitive matching using XPath (at least in XPath 1.0, version that is supported by .NET). One known way is using `translate()` to convert `Display_Name` value to lower-case before doing further comparison, something like this (see [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625446/problem-with-upper-case-and-lower-case-xpath-functions-in-selenium-ide/1625859#1625859)) :

```
var xpath = @"//*[
                contains(
                    translate(@Display_Name
                              ,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                              ,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                    )
                    ,'a'
                )
            ]";
var result = root.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

Comment: Hi @har07, what is the significance of  ->  ,'a' .. Just curious

Comment: @ShubhamJain from the quoted section : *"...using xPath having **"A"** [regardless of capitals or small] in Display_Name attribute"*

Answer (score 0):

Try with below XPath

```
/ParentNode/ChildNode/@Display_Name
```

To get result for both

Above XPath will return you all results of ChildNode. Now iterate this XPath to extract all results

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: But how to make it filter with wild search in all the ChildNodes?

Comment: And as u suggested, I've tried 

docGetInternal.SelectNodes("/DISPLAY_TABLE_FIELDS_LOOKUP_TABLE/DISPLAY_TABLE_FIELDS_LOOKUP_ROW[contains(.,'end')]");

but it is not working in my case either.

Answer (score 0):

Use OuterXml method.

Try this:

```
//Load Data     
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);

//Go the xPath
XmlNode titleNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath);

//Get the OutXml (You dont need to use a new variable)
string nodeValue = titleNode.OuterXml;

//Load this string as a new XmlDocument and use the second xPath
XmlDocument xmlDoc2 = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc2.LoadXml(nodeValue);
titleNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath2);
```