# How to find elements through text ignoring the case using Selenium and Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, uppercase, xpath-1.0

I'm using java version "1.8.0_191" and selenium 3.141.59.

I'm trying to find out if a page contains the word "error" or "erreur". Also, I want it to be case insensitive.

Finding a text is easy:

```
List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'error')]"));
```

By I'm having a harder time making it case insensitive. So far I tried this (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1625446/10512595)):

```
List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body//text()[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'error')]"));
```

But it return the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: TypeError: Expected an element or WindowProxy, got: [object Text] {}
```

I also tried this:

```
 List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(transate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'error')]"));
```

But it doesn't work either (since it's not a legal expression).

So, any idea in how to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a *list*  of elements within an webpage containing the text **error** ignoring the upper/lower cases you can use the [`translate()`](https://www.w3cschool.cn/doc_xslt_xpath/xslt_xpath-xpath-functions-translate.html) function within an [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) as follows:

- Syntax:

  ```
  translate('some text','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
  ```
- Line of Code:

  ```
  List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'error')]"));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

XPATH 2 allows to do case insensitive matches but most browsers have XPATH 1.

Your best bet will be to use combination of text in one XPATH. Like :

```
"//*[contains(text(), 'error') or contains(text(), 'ERROR') or contains(text(), 'erreur') or contains(text(), 'ERREUR')]"

OR

"//*[contains(text(), 'error')] | //*[contains(text(), 'ERROR')] | //*[contains(text(), 'erreur')] | //*[contains(text(), 'ERREUR')]"
```