# How can I use XPath contains() for a few values under 1 common class?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation

I need create a Xpath for an expression like -

```
(trim(STRING_1)=upper(STRING_2))
```

but unfortunately this expression is located in some editor, the code is -

```
<div class="ace_line" style="height: 16px;">
 <span class="ace_paren ace_lparen">  (  </span>
 <span class="ace_support ace_function">  trim  </span>
 <span class="ace_paren ace_lparen">  (  </span>
 <span class="ace_storage ace_type">  STRING_1  </span>
 <span class="ace_paren ace_rparen">  )  </span> 
 <span class="ace_keyword ace_operator">  =  </span> 
 <span class="ace_support ace_function">  upper  </span>
 <span class="ace_paren ace_lparen">  (  </span>
 <span class="ace_storage ace_type">  STRING_2  </span>
 <span class="ace_paren ace_rparen">  ))  </span></div>
```

(extra spaces for best visualization)

How can I create a Xpath for the whole expression?

It should be something like -

```
//*[contains(text(),'(', 'trim', '(', 'STRING_1', ')', '=', 'upper', '(', 'STRING_2', '))')]
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: if `ace_line` is unique in HTMLDOM, you can do getAttribute on it and call innerText, you don't have to have all these contains and trim in your xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `contains()` in a single XPath expression like:

```java
"//*[contains(text(),'(') and contains(text(),'trim') and contains(text(),'STRING_1') and contains(text(),'=') and contains(text(),'upper') and contains(text(),'STRING_2') and contains(text(),')') and contains(text(),'))')]"
```

You can also use something like this:

```java
"//div[.//span[contains(text(), 'trim') and .//span[contains(text(), 'upper')]]"
```

Comment: I am trying the line - 
//div[span[contains(text(), 'trim') and contains(text(), 'upper')]] but it doesn't work

Comment: No, that's wrong. it is not the same `span` element having the `trim` text and the `upper` text

Comment: See my updated answer for how to locate parent element based on 2 child elements

Answer (score 0):

The texts *`trim`* and *`upper`* can be at any position within the `<div class="ace_line"...>`.

---

### Solution

You can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *xpath* using the texts *trim* and *upper*:

  ```
  "//div[@class='ace_line'][.//span[contains(., 'trim')]][.//span[contains(., 'upper')]]"
  ```
- *xpath* ignoring the case of *`STRING_1`*:

  ```
  "//div[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'STRING_1')]"
  ```
- *xpath* ignoring the case of *`STRING_1`* and *`STRING_2`*:

  ```
  "//div[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'STRING_1')][contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'STRING_2')]"
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to find elements through text ignoring the case using Selenium and Xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56477271/7429447)