# How to create case insensitive xpath in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, case-insensitive

I have created below XPath but it is not working as expected.

I am checking text in the cell of a html table and I want a particular cell to be matched.

I have created below XPath but it is not working.

```
*//table[@id="customerPortalTable"]//tbody//tr[td[ contains(translate(text(), "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), "{0}") ]]
```

`{0}` - This is the place holder for value to search

I want to match below values

Test Account or TEST ACCOUNT or Test ACCOUNT

```
<td class="left filterInputColumn">Test Account</td>
<td class="left filterInputColumn">Test ACCOUNT</td>
<td class="left filterInputColumn">TEST ACCOUNT</td>
```

Comment: an example of what you are attempting to match and what value you are providing would be helpful. For instance, are you searching with an UPPER-CASE value? Does your HTML have a table with that `@id`? Does the table have `tdbody`? All questions that we have no answers to.

Comment: It does have table with that ID. I want to match this - Test Account as well as TEST ACCOUNT. I want do match not case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally your XPath looks ok to me. Maybe the issue is connected with whether you search uppercase or lowercase, for example these both are returning the three td nodes:

```
 //td[contains(translate(text(), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 'TEST ACCOUNT')]
 
 //td[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'test account')]
```

Answer (score 0):

To create the case insensitive [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) you can use the following solution:

```
"//table[@id="customerPortalTable"]//tbody//tr[.//td[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '{}')]]".format(placeholder)
```

Effectively, your line of code will be:

```
placeholder= "Test Account"
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id="customerPortalTable"]//tbody//tr[.//td[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '{}')]]".format(placeholder)));
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to find elements through text ignoring the case using Selenium and Xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56477271/7429447)