# xml data in upper-case

Tags: css, xslt

I have a xslt file that fetches data from a xml file and displays them accordingly. Some of the data in the xml file are in lower-case. Is there any way by which I can change it to upper-case inside the xslt while displaying it in the table? my xslt file is as given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
      <head>
        <title>VPGate Media Mixer</title>

        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate"/>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15"></meta>
        <script src="/Common/common.js\" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style001.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Grid.Default.css" />


      </head>

      <body class="WorkArea">
        <div class="divSummaryHeader" id="SummaryHeader">
          <h1>Media Mixer - VPGate</h1>

          <xsl:for-each select="MMDiagnostics/Conference">
            <h1>
              Media Mixer - <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </h1>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </div>

        &#160;



        <div class="RadGrid RadGrid_Default" id="SummaryData" style="position:absolute;width:810px;height:510px;overflow:auto">

          <table border="0" class="rgMasterTable rgClipCells" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
            <tr>
              <input type="button" class="formEditBtn" id="SubBtn" value="Refresh" onclick="window.location=window.location;"/>


            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;" colspan="2">Conference Summary</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <table border="0" class="rgMasterTable rgClipCells" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  >
                  <tr>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Conference Name</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Conference ID</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Composite Address</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Composite Port</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Composite Ssrc</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">No Of Participants</td>
                  </tr>

                  <xsl:if test="MediaMixer!= ''">
                    <xsl:for-each select="MediaMixer/Conference">
                      <!--<xsl:sort select="Name"/>-->
                      <xsl:if test="Name !=''">
                        <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2 = 0)">

                          <tr class="rgAltRow SummaryTableDataRow">
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="ConfId"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="CompositeAddress"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="CompositePort"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="CompositeSsrc"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="NoOfParticipants"/>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </xsl:if>


                        <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2 = 1)">
                          <td>
                            <tr class="rgRow SummaryTableDataRow">
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ConfId"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="CompositeAddress"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="CompositePort"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="CompositeSsrc"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="NoOfParticipants"/>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </td>
                        </xsl:if>
                      </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="MediaMixer = ''">
                    <td valign = "top">
                      <xsl:text>No Data </xsl:text>
                    </td>
                  </xsl:if>

                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          &#160;

          <table border="0" class="rgMasterTable rgClipCells" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"  >
            <tr>
              <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;" colspan="2">Conference Details</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>

                <table border="0" class="rgMasterTable rgClipCells" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
                  <tr>

                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Conference Name</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Conference ID</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Participant ID 1</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Participant ID 2</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Participant Address</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Participant Listening Port</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">MM Listening Port</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">SSRC From Participant</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">SSRC From MM</td>
                  </tr>





                  <xsl:if test="MediaMixer!= ''">

                    <xsl:for-each select="MediaMixer/Conference">


                      <xsl:for-each  select="Participant">

                        <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2 = 0)">
                          <tr class="rgAltRow SummaryTableDataRow">
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="../Name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="../ConfId"/>
                            </td>

                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:variable name="text" select="'Upper'" />
                              <xsl:value-of select="translate($text, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" />
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="ID2"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="ParticipantAddress"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="ParticipantListeningPort"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="MMListeningPort"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="SSRCFromParticipant"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="SSRCFromMM"/>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2 = 1)">
                          <td>
                            <tr class="rgRow SummaryTableDataRow">

                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="../Name"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="../ConfId"/>
                              </td>

                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ID1"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ID2"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ParticipantAddress"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ParticipantListeningPort"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="MMListeningPort"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="SSRCFromParticipant"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="SSRCFromMM"/>
                              </td>

                            </tr>
                          </td>
                        </xsl:if>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:if>


                  <xsl:if test="MediaMixer= ''">

                    <td valign = "top">
                      <xsl:text>No Data </xsl:text>
                    </td>
                  </xsl:if>

                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>


          &#160;


          <div style="display:none">
            <iframe id="frameUpdate" name="frameUpdate" width="100%"></iframe>
          </div>


        </div>

      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Let us assume that I wish to change **ID1** to upper-case. How do i do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207098/xslt-stylesheet-changing-text-to-upper-case

Comment: so wat ??? i hav d same query of a different kind

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226263/xslt-xpath-no-upper-case-function-in-msxml-4-0/1226293#1226293

Answer (score 0):

Add at the top, before `<xsl:template match="/">`:

```
<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
```

And your `ID1` selector will be probably:

```
<td valign = "top">
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(ID1, $smallcase, $uppercase)" />
</td>
```